# Deferred: Temporary AUTH failure with SMTP Relay over port 587

Tags: docker, ssl, smtp, sendmail

I would like to use `sendmail` in a docker container to send email. I was able to do this before for my own site when I used [a certain script](https://gitlab.com/aninternetpresence/docker-demos/blob/master/laravel/setup-mail.sh) to set everything up.

When I try this now `sendmail` tells me `Deferred: Temporary AUTH failure` but the next line says `Message accepted for delivery`. However, the message is not sent as I use Mailgun for SMTP credentials and their logs never report the email that `sendmail` tries to send. I have confirmed my Mailgun credentials are still valid because I can use their REST API to send mail.

I noticed when I change the port from `587` to `465` or `25` in the `sendmail.mc`, it is not able to connect to `smtp.mailgun.org` at all. It is only when I use port `587` that I get as far as the `Temporary AUTH failure`. How can I resolve this authorization failure? I'm 100% sure that the correct credentials are in my `/etc/mail/authinfo/auth` file. I tried ending that file with `"M:LOGIN"`, `"M:PLAIN"`, and `"M:PLAIN LOGIN"`, and `"M:EXTERNAL"` but to no avail.

How on earth do I configure `sendmail` to send mail with my Mailgun SMTP credentials over port 587 without this "Deferred: Temporary AUTH failure" error?

Comment: I'm even more certain my SMTP credentials are fine because I can use the [Swift Mailer](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer) API to send mail without issue. Is anyone else able to get sendmail to send mail from the [php:apache](https://store.docker.com/images/php) docker container?

Comment: Oh come on... No one has ever setup sendmail in the [php:apache](https://store.docker.com/images/php) docker container? I'm going to be the first person to figure it out?

Comment: No, you're just posting on the wrong site. Yours is not a programming question; voting to close as off-topic for Stack Overflow. Maybe try [su] or [unix.se] but read their posting guidelines (too) before asking there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I don't think I will ever use pure `sendmail` ever again. I ended up using `ssmtp` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47485123/1180714).