# Awk permission denied when run through msmtp

Tags: bash, email, awk, gnupg, msmtp

I am using `gpg2` and `awk` jointly with msmtp to send emails in emacs. This is the relevant portion of my `.msmtprc` file

```
account gmail
host smtp.gmail.com
from myusername@gmail.com
auth on
port 465
user myusername@gmail.com
passwordeval gpg2 -q --for-your-eyes-only --no-tty -d ~/.authinfo.gpg | awk '/machine smtp.gmail.com login myusername@gmail.com/ {print $NF}'
```

and this is how my .authinfo.gpg file looks like

```
machine smtp.gmail.com login myusername@gmail.com port 465 password myverysecretpassword
machine imap.gmail.com login myusername@gmail.com port 993 password myverysecretpassword
```

For some reason the command in the above passwordeval field runs fine in the terminal, i.e. it outputs the password, but when I run it with msmtp

```
echo -e "Subject: Test Mail\r\n\r\nThis is a test mail" |msmtp --debug --from=default -t myusername@gmail.com
```

awk returns a permission error.

```
loaded user configuration file /home/myusername/.msmtprc
falling back to default account
sh: 1: awk: Permission denied
msmtp: cannot read output of 'gpg2 -q --for-your-eyes-only --no-tty -d ~/.authinfo.gpg | awk '/machine smtp.gmail.com login myusername@gmail.com/ {print $NF}''
```

I'm completely at a loss of what might be wrong here. This issue appeared after an OS upgrade. I have run chmod 600 on the .msmtprc file as well. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Other info**

- I've tried to use plain password temporarily and it works
- I've tried to give 777 permissions to .msmtprc temporarily and it didn't work
- I've tried to reinstall `msmtp` and it didn't work
- I've tried to use `sed` instead of `awk` and I get an identical permission error (for sed).
- This other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880689/linux-msmtp-configuration-sends-from-shell-but-fails-from-php-apache) might be related? It sort of suggests that the .msmtprc owner might be relevant. In my case I am the owner of the file.

Versions used

GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.2.0)
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2019 Free Software Foundation.

gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.19
libgcrypt 1.8.5
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

msmtp version 1.8.6
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
TLS/SSL library: GnuTLS

Comment: are you running as root? Those permissions only give access to root.

Comment: According to this https://vigasdeep.com/2014/05/06/installing-and-configuring-msmtp/ chmod 600 should be sufficient. I never had to use sudo in the past (before the OS upgrade)

Comment: @samthegolden actually, I've looked at the file permissions of msmtp and it has the setgid (s) permission, which means that anyone should be able to run it as root? `-rwxr-sr-x 1 root msmtp 130728 Oct 11  2019 /usr/bin/msmtp`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to advice from marlam I found out that this issue is due to an overly restrictive AppArmor profile for msmtp. I am led to assume that my new OS version is more stringent with regards to usage of msmtp (good thing I guess). Unfortunately this often happens on Debian and Ubuntu and it confuses many users. The commands I've used to solve it are

```sh
sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.msmtp /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.msmtp
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the AppArmor protection is one solution. Augmenting the AppArmor profile to include `awk` is a better solution.

In `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.msmtp` add the following line:

```
*** usr.bin.msmtp.old   2022-01-13 08:22:33.301883304 +0100
--- usr.bin.msmtp       2022-01-13 08:23:41.550280850 +0100
***************
*** 50,55 ****
--- 50,57 ----
      /tmp/            rw,
      owner /tmp/*     rw,
  
+     /usr/bin/awk         PUx,
      /usr/bin/secret-tool PUx,
      /usr/bin/gpg{,2}     PUx,
      /usr/bin/pass        PUx,
```

so that the `helpers` section looks like this:

```
  # secret helpers
  /{,usr/}bin/bash Cx -> helpers,
  /{,usr/}bin/dash Cx -> helpers,
  profile helpers {
    #include <abstractions/base>
    /{,usr/}bin/bash mr,
    /{,usr/}bin/dash mr,
    /tmp/            rw,
    owner /tmp/*     rw,

    /usr/bin/awk         PUx,
    /usr/bin/secret-tool PUx,
    /usr/bin/gpg{,2}     PUx,
    /usr/bin/pass        PUx,
    /usr/bin/head        PUx,
    /usr/bin/keyring     PUx,
    /{,usr/}bin/cat      PUx,
  }
```

Afterwards run

```sh
# Mind the small r (reload), do not use capital R (remove)
sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.msmtp
```

Comment: Is this is factually incorrect? Then  please fix/comment this , I don’t understand the down vote.